# asp .net list control binding

Tags: asp.net, listview, repeater

First of all sorry about the bad title but i didn't know how to describe my problem correctly.

Well, i am quite new to asp .net so go on easy on me ^^

I have html file with a structure like the following :

```
<ul id="Ministries">
    <li id="Ministry1"> Ministry1 title</li>
    <li id="Ministry2"> Ministry2 title </li>
    <li id="Ministry3"> Ministry3 title </li>
</ul>
<ul id="ministryDescriptions">
    <li id="Ministry1Description"> 
        <div id="Ministry title" class="x"> Ministry1 description</div>
        <li id="Ministry1Services">
            <ul id="Ministry1servicesTtiles">
                <li id="Ministry1Service1">Ministry1Service1Title</li>
                <li id="Ministry1Service2">Ministry1Service2Title</li>
                <li id="Ministry1Service3">Ministry1Service3Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="Ministry1servicesDetails">
                <li id="Ministry1Service1Details">
                    <div id="service1description" > desc service1 of ministry1</div>
                    <p>whatever here</p>
                    <ul id="Ministry1Service1RequiredDocs">
                        <li id="Ministry1Service1RequiredDoc1">Doc1</li>
                        <li id="Ministry1Service1RequiredDoc2">Doc2</li>
                        <li id="Ministry1Service1RequiredDoc3">Doc3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="Ministry1Service2Details"></li>
                <li id="Ministry1Service3Details"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
    <li id="Ministry2Description"> </li>
    <li id="Ministry3Description"> </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting objects from database in a List where Ministrry has attributes like

```
    public class MinistryModel
    {
        public string MinistryName { get; set; }
        public string MinistryMission { get; set; }
        public string MinistryVision { get; set; }
        public string MinistrySpecialities { get; set; }
        public string MinistryUrl { get; set; }
        public List<string> MinistryServices { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to find a way to generate this structure in that exact html form and structure with the database objects.

I used to use Asp:ListView bit in this case the ul and li are not (all) nested, this is why i am a bit lost.

I hope you understood my problem and waiting forward for some help.

PS: I can't change HTML structure i must use it as it is

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what source your data is coming from so this is general code for use of DataList for your example.

```html
<asp:DataList ID="DataListTitles" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate> DataBinder info for Ministry# title</ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    


    <asp:DataList ID="DataListDescriptions" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>DataBinder info for Ministry# Description</div><ul>
      </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
     -DataBinder info for Ministry# Service# Titles
     -DataBinder info for Ministry1servicesDetails
     -DataBinder info for Docs
    </ItemTemplate>

   

    <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use nested Listviews to have the exact output.
Or simply create the HTML code dynamically on codebehind.